# The use of "go through" in context

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is it correct to use *go through* in the sense passing something. For example:

> On my way home I will be **going through** the grocery store, so I can get you something.

What I am trying to say is that I will be going past the store in my car.

Comment: No, we would never use **go through** to mean **drive past**; it means 'go in, and out at the other side' (or possibly 'walk round' the store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use "going through" in this case. As Kate Bunting mentions, it would mean that you drive through the store - that is not what you mean.

["Go through something"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-through-sth) is also a set phrase with some distinct meanings that is very different than what you intend to convey.

There are other ways around this.

> I will be driving by the grocery store on my way home; I will get you something.

or

> There is a grocery store on the way home; I will get you something. [or 'The grocery store is on the way home; ...']

or

> I will be passing by the grocery store on my way home; I will get you something.